# magento custome api connection to economics

Tags: magento

I am running an api for magento shop to connect to economics : please check this link for that api : https://github.com/tkjaergaard/Economic-PHP-SDK?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C1957533932

I just paste the folder in root directory and getting my order through

```
$orderId= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order= Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

My question is I need to include api folder in root director / vendor / autoload.php file for connection  my extension.... 
So that when an new order is been placed in my shop the total order details  will be automatically add to economics api...

Any idea on this... thanks in advance.

Create a new Order This method lets you create a newOrder to a specific Debtor.Theaddmethod on thelineobject accepts a array containing information on the product line. The array accepts the following elements:*.Product: The product number.required*.Description: The line description.optional*.Price: The unit price of the line.optional*.Qty: The quantity of the line.optional*.Unit: The Unit number to use.optional

```
<?php
require(Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'Economic-PHP-SDK-master'.DS.'vendor'.DS.'autoload.php');
use tkj\Economics\Client;
use tkj\Economics\Order\Order;
$client = new Client($agreementNumber,$userID, $password);
$order = new Order($client);
$debtorNumber = 101;
$newOrder =$order->create($debtorNumber, function($line)
{
 $data = array(
"product"     => 301,
"description" => "Description of line.",
"price"       => 825.00,
"qty"         => 5,
"unit"        => 2);
$line->add($data);
});
```

class EconomicAPI_Model_Observer {

```
public function ordermigrate($observer) {


    $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

    // echo "order subtotal: ".$order->getSubtotal()."<br>";
    // echo "shipping: ".$order->getShippingAmount()."<br>";
    // echo "discount: ".$order->getDiscountAmount()."<br>";
    // echo "tax: ".$order->getTaxAmount()."<br>";
    // echo "grand total".$order->getGrandTotal()."<br><br><br>";

    $to = 'karthickica@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Mail before Sale order place.';
    $message =  $orderId ;
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );

}
```

}

Comment: You use a back-tick, not a single-quote to format code. Back-tick is the key under the tilde (~).

Comment: Here i tried to connect this api by my custome extenion , The first path i added for connection through the api and second part is my extension model to get the oders will sent a mail to my id with order id which the last order  placed in the shop by session.